# Replace parent JSON object using Regex Sublime Text

Tags: json, regex, sublimetext2

I have json like this.

```
{
   "1": {
       "username": "trinimedic",
       "followers_numb": 336,

   },
   "2": {
       "username": "juanjose731",
       "followers_numb": 17,

   },
   "3": {
       "username": "Purwadi52879356",
       "followers_numb": 4,

   }
}
```

i want to remove the parent which contains number. So json will like this :

```
{
   {
       "username": "trinimedic",
       "followers_numb": 336,

   },
   {
       "username": "juanjose731",
       "followers_numb": 17,

   },
   {
       "username": "Purwadi52879356",
       "followers_numb": 4,

   }
}
```

How to replace using regex in sublime text?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know how to replace using regex? Then just put `"\d":\s` in the "Find What:" box and leave "Replace With:" box empty. Then just hit "Replace All".

I hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you select * in sublime when searching

```
\"([0-9])*\"
```

Answer (score 1):

Find :`"\d+"\s*:\s*`

Replace With empty

And make sure enable sublime text `.*` button